# Individual multiple column sorting in excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to sort multiple columns in excel independently. I have a ton of columns, but keeping the order between rows isn't important. Any easy tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a macros. To write a macros make sure to go into the development ribbon section and add it in:

```
Sub SortIndividualJR()
    Dim rngFirstRow As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngFirstRow = ws.Range("A1:JR1")
    For Each rng In rngFirstRow
        With ws.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=rng, Order:=xlAscending
            'assuming there are no blank cells..
            .SetRange ws.Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown))
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Apply
        End With
    Next rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

You can change the range to fit how many columns you have.

Comment: I'm confused. I don't see a "development ribbon"

Comment: In Excel 2010 up go into preferences and then add in the development ribbon. Make sure the macros tool is visible. Within it you should be able to run it easily.

Comment: Write the macros name in the heading and hit create. Then copy paste it in and then hit run

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't need to be a "Code" Answer:

Have you tried using the "sort column" feature found under `Home Ribbon>Sort&Filter>Custom Sort>Options` and then select "Sort Left to Right"

Comment: I have, but I want multiple columns independently sorted. I have a lot of data and don't want to do each column one at a time.